# Pressure Sensitivity with Wacom Bamboo in Inkscape 0.48

Tags: input-devices, wacom, inkscape

The pressure sensitivity for my Wacom Bamboo Pen & Touch in Inkscape 0.48 (running Ubuntu 12.04) does not work.

I ticked all options in `Input Devices` (Wacom Bamboo 16FG 4x5 Pen stylus; Wacom Bamboo 16FG 4x5 Pen eraser; Wacom Bamboo 16FG 4x5 Finger touch; Wacom Bamboo 16FG 4x5 Finger pad). Also ticked `Use pressure-sensitive tablet` in the `Mouse` dialog in `Inkscape Preferences`.

The pen (both sides: pen and eraser) works fine as a pointer but that's it. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please uninstall the overlay scrollbar package from ubuntu, go into the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get purge overlay-scrollbar
```

Then rerun Inkscape with the tablet plugged in.

Comment: What does this do? What is `overlay-scrollbar` and where is it needed?

Comment: This actually works! Pressure has finally noticeable effects.

Comment: From the launchpad website https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/overlay-scrollbar : "Overlay Scrollbars use an overlay to ensure that scrollbars take up no active screen real-estate. A thumb appears magically when the pointer is in proximity to the scrollbar, for easy desktop-style paging and dragging."

Comment: I just had the same issue again, this time with Ubuntu 14.04 and can confirm. Pressure sensitivity now works in Inkscape 0.48.

Comment: It only seems to work though if you plug in the Bamboo FIRST and then open Inkscape!

Comment: inkscape stopped working after that. I had to install it back so it wasn't a solution for me.

Comment: It worked for me, but why does it work?

Comment: We have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to uninstall the scrollbar.

Just use the Unity Tweak Tool and disable it from there, in System->Scrolling, by choosing Legacy.

[image: Just select legacy to disable]